# Changing scope from member to global function

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to change a print function from a member to a global function without modifying the main function. I am unable to compile this without modifying the main function, though.

```
class Student
{
char* name; 
long ssn; 
     public:
     Student (char*, long);
     //void print();
     char * getName ( );
     long getSsn ( );
};

Student::Student(char* temp_name, long temp_ssn)
{
    name = new char[strlen(temp_name) +1];
    strcpy(name,temp_name);
    ssn = temp_ssn;
}

char * Student::getName()
{
    return name;
}

long Student::getSsn()
{
    return ssn;
}

void print()
{
    cout << "Name: " << getName() << endl;
    cout << "SSN: " << getSsn() << endl;
}

int main ( ) 
{
    Student S1("Mike", 222222222L);
    S1.print();
    return 0; 
}
```

In particular, I was wondering if it is necessary to include void print(); in the public: section of the Student class? Or would that make it a member function?

Is it actually possible to do this without modifying the main function?

How do I access the class from a global function? Am I going to go crazy? Thank you, everyone.

Comment: No it's not possible. In the `main` function `print` is being called as a member function. So if you make it a global function you're going to have to change `main`. And you're going to have to change the function itself, at the moment your global `print` does not compile.

Comment: Thank you, it's a class assignment and I wasn't sure if the instructor was asking for something impossible (again). I'll change the main and rework the print function. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @PresidentRobo I expect you just misunderstood him, maybe he doesn't explain himself very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to make `print` a global function.

```
class Student
{
char* name; 
long ssn; 
     public:
     Student (char*, long);
     char * getName ( );
     long getSsn ( );
};

Student::Student(char* temp_name, long temp_ssn)
{
    name = new char[strlen(temp_name) +1];
    strcpy(name,temp_name);
    ssn = temp_ssn;
}

char * Student::getName()
{
    return name;
}

long Student::getSsn()
{
    return ssn;
}

void print(Student& s)
{
    cout << "Name: " << s.getName() << endl;
    cout << "SSN: " << s.getSsn() << endl;
}

int main ( ) 
{
    Student S1("Mike", 222222222L);
    print(S1);
    return 0; 
}
```

Notice that I've added a `Student&` parameter to `print`, it has to know which student to print after all. And in `main` I've changed the way `print` is called so it has a `Student` parameter, instead of calling a method on `Student`.

I'm sure the point of the exercise is to show that you can achieve the same effects using either global functions or member functions.

Comment: Oh, okay! That's a huge help. I'll look into the use of pointers here a little more. I can't figure out why you're using "Student& s" here instead of just "Student s" Learning new things is fun

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the actual assignment. That would seem like cheating? So I just wrote something smaller up with the same general idea...

Comment: @pr `Student s`

Comment: `Student& s` is an example of *passing by reference*. Writing `Student s` would make a copy of your student object before printing it. This should work fine, assuming that your `Student` object can be copied (which depends on the detail of it's implementation, this is a big topic which no doubt you will cover in the future). But generally speaking with objects it is preferred to pass a reference to the object, this avoids copying the object, which is a little more efficient.

Comment: @PresidentRobo passing with `Student s` will make a copy to  pass to the function. & will pass a reference and save on a copy. Also use the `const` keyword if all you doing is displaying data.  give both your methods and function parameters this keyword if you are not gone modify the data passed.
It will help you find errors in the future.

Comment: yup, the next section is using const. Thank you both your your help and explanations :)